# Is there a trickle-like tool to set IP ToS?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, qos

I've set up my router to traffic shape using the [ToS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_of_service) field, but not all bandwidth-heavy programs set an appropriate value. So I need a way to set the ToS for the traffic of an arbitrary program.

Is there a tool that would work like [trickle](http://linux.die.net/man/1/trickle) but set ToS instead of a bandwidth limit, so that I could launch programs using it to have them shaped on the router? Or some other way to manage the ToS of a program's traffic without cooperation from that program?

Requirements:

- Must be transparent to the program, not require any modification to it.
- Must not depend on a particular port: both programs that use many ports and programs that share a port with others should be usable independently.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -t mangle -p tcp --sport ssh -j TOS --set-tos Minimize-Delay
```

Comment: I'm not proficient with using iptables, but I think that affects all traffic to a given port? My use case requires it to affect some programs that generate traffic to multiple ports, and some that use port 80 which the browser also uses.